# I am trying to shoot multiple of bullets using pygame group module but I don't know how to do it properly

Tags: python, pygame

**Problem 1:** I am trying to shoot maximum of 5 bullets using pygame group class module but I can only shoot maximum of 1 bullet...

This is the bullet class:

```
class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,image,location):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = image
    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
    self.location =location
    self.rect.left,self.rect.top = self.location
```

Down below: I have set 'bullet' as a sprite

```
def bullet_group(group):
    for bullet in group:
        print(group.sprites)

        group.remove(bullet)
        #    After shooting a bullet, I want to remove the bullet from the group
        #    in order to change the 'shoot_point'(which is the location of the bullet) 
        #    back to where it starts

        shoot_point_x = fixed_shoot_point_x  #fixed_shoot_point is the start location
        shoot_point_y = fixed_shoot_point_y  #of the bullet

        group.add(bullet)
```

Just before the main while loop:

```
group=pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(0,5):
    group.add(bullet)
```

I made 5 bullet sprites

In the main code down below:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if #some code

    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fixed_bullet_speed_change = [round(-(math.cos(math.atan2(RealTank.Trect.centery-shoot_point_y,RealTank.Trect.centerx-shoot_point_x))),1)*10,round(-(math.sin(math.atan2(RealTank.Trect.centery-shoot_point_y,RealTank.Trect.centerx-shoot_point_x))),1)*10]
        #  the line of code above is just some calculations that is not related to the question

        group.remove(bullet)
        #  I removed the sprite from the group after shooting some bullets, in order to 
        #  shoot another one

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
     if #some code

     elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            group.add(bullet)
        #  adding back another one
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong????

**Problem 2:**
When I do 'print(group.sprites)' and press 'SPACEBAR', I get more sprites every time I press it...

==================================================================

**Here's all of my code down below**:(*you don't need to see it...it isn't necessary*)

Try the code down below, to visualize my problem

**pictures:**

[image: Tank]
[image: turret][image: bullet]

```
import pygame,math
pygame.init()
red = (155,0,0)
class Tanks(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image,location,angle,speed,x_change,y_change,
                 turret_image,turret_angle,bullet_image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.turret_image = pygame.image.load(turret_image)
        self.bullet_image = pygame.image.load(bullet_image)
        self.Brect = self.bullet_image.get_rect()
        self.Trect = self.turret_image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left,self.rect.top=location
        self.Trect.centerx,self.Trect.bottom = self.rect.centerx,self.rect.centery
        self.angle = angle
        self.turret_angle = turret_angle
        self.speed = speed
        self.x_change = x_change
        self.y_change = y_change


        print(self.angle)

    def rotate(self):
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image,self.angle)
        rot_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        return rot_image,rot_rect

    def turret_rotate(self):
        turret_rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.turret_image,self.turret_angle)
        turret_rot_rect = turret_rot_image.get_rect(center = self.Trect.midbottom)
        return turret_rot_image,turret_rot_rect

##    def bullet_rotate(self):
##        bullet_rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bullet_image,self.turret_angle)
##        bullet_rot_rect = bullet_rot_image.get_rect(center = )

    def moving_after_angle_change(self):
        x=round(math.cos(math.radians(self.angle+90)),1)*self.speed
        y=round(math.sin(math.radians(self.angle-90)),1)*self.speed
        return x,y

    def shoot_point(self):
        #print(self.turret_angle)
        shoot_point_x = RealTank.Trect.centerx + math.cos(math.radians(RealTank.turret_angle+90))*55
        shoot_point_y = RealTank.Trect.centery + math.sin(math.radians(RealTank.turret_angle-90))*55
        return shoot_point_x,shoot_point_y

class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image,location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.location =location
        self.rect.left,self.rect.top = self.location

def bullet_group(group):
    for bullet in group:
        print(group.sprites)
        group.remove(bullet)
        shoot_point_x = fixed_shoot_point_x
        shoot_point_y = fixed_shoot_point_y
        group.add(bullet)

#initial
player_image_str = 'Tank.png'
player_turret_str = 'turret - Copy.png'
player_gold_bullet_str = 'bullet.png'

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

display_width,display_height = 900,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([display_width,display_height])

player_location = [600,300]
player_angle = 0
player_angle_change = 0
player_speed = 0
player_x_change=0
player_y_change=0
RealTank_x_change_store=0
RealTank_y_change_store=0

turret_angle = 0
turret_angle_change = 0
bullet_speed_change = [0,0]
fixed_bullet_speed = [0,0]
fixed_bullet_speed_change = [0,0]
shoot_point_x = 0
shoot_point_y=0
fixed_shoot_point_x=0
fixed_shoot_point_y=0
#main
RealTank = Tanks(player_image_str,player_location,player_angle,player_speed,
                     player_x_change,player_y_change,player_turret_str,turret_angle,player_gold_bullet_str)
bullet=Bullets(RealTank.bullet_image,[shoot_point_x,shoot_point_y])
group=pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(0,5):
    group.add(bullet)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                turret_angle_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                turret_angle_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed=2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed=-2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_angle_change = 2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_angle_change = -2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fixed_bullet_speed_change = [round(-(math.cos(math.atan2(RealTank.Trect.centery-shoot_point_y,RealTank.Trect.centerx-shoot_point_x))),1)*10,round(-(math.sin(math.atan2(RealTank.Trect.centery-shoot_point_y,RealTank.Trect.centerx-shoot_point_x))),1)*10]
                group.remove(bullet)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                turret_angle_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_angle_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_angle_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                group.add(bullet)

    player_angle+=player_angle_change
    turret_angle+=turret_angle_change
    RealTank = Tanks(player_image_str,player_location,player_angle,player_speed,
                     player_x_change,player_y_change,player_turret_str,turret_angle,player_gold_bullet_str)

    RealTank.image,RealTank.rect=RealTank.rotate()

    RealTank.turret_image,RealTank.Trect = RealTank.turret_rotate()

    RealTank.x_change,RealTank.y_change=RealTank.moving_after_angle_change()

    RealTank_x_change_store += RealTank.x_change
    RealTank_y_change_store += RealTank.y_change
    RealTank.Trect.centerx +=RealTank_x_change_store
    RealTank.Trect.centery +=RealTank_y_change_store
    RealTank.rect.centerx += RealTank_x_change_store
    RealTank.rect.centery += RealTank_y_change_store

    shoot_point_x,shoot_point_y=RealTank.shoot_point()
    fixed_shoot_point_x,fixed_shoot_point_y = RealTank.shoot_point()
    screen.fill([0,0,0])
    screen.blit(RealTank.image,RealTank.rect)

    #bullet
    print(fixed_bullet_speed_change)
    fixed_bullet_speed[0]+=fixed_bullet_speed_change[0]
    fixed_bullet_speed[1]+=fixed_bullet_speed_change[1]
    shoot_point_x+=fixed_bullet_speed[0]
    shoot_point_y+=fixed_bullet_speed[1]
    #bullet end
    bullet=Bullets(RealTank.bullet_image,[shoot_point_x,shoot_point_y])

    #bullet group


    bullet_group(group)
    #bullet group end
    screen.blit(bullet.image,bullet.location)
    screen.blit(RealTank.turret_image,RealTank.Trect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create only one instance of bullet - you need 5 instances

```
group = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(5):
    bullet = Bullets(RealTank.bullet_image, [shoot_point_x, shoot_point_y])
    group.add(bullet)
```

> Doc: [pygame.sprite.Group.add()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.add):
>
> Add any number of Sprites to this Group. **This will only add Sprites
>   that are not already members of the Group.**

---

Inside `while loop` you create new bullet `bullet = Bullets()` (variable name `bullet` doesn't matter, `id(bullet)` do matter) and you try to remove it (`remove(bullet)`) but this instance is not in group so it removes nothing. And later you add bullet (`add(bullet)`) and it adds it because this instance is not in group yet.

Comment: I don't know where to put remove(bullet) and add(bullet)... can you help?

Comment: as for me `remove()` and `add()` are in good place - but `bullet=Bullets()` is in wrong place. It should be right before `add()`.

Comment: BTW: I think big mistake is: in `while True` you create new instance of `Bullets` (and `Tank`) to show it in new place.it doesn't make sense. Create one instance of Tank and change only its parameters when it is needed. The same with bullets create new instance only when you fire new bullet, not all the time.